# Filterable and searchable list of orders in Laravel Eloquent Query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am working on implementation of a table with list of restaurant orders, that is filterable and searchable. On my front-end I have a state with variables like: `searchQuery, dateRange (in following format ['2021-01-01', '2022-08-01']), provider_id (restaurants ID), paid (if order is paid - bool), notPaid - bool`. On submit I am sending the query to back-end.

What I need is to include all parameters from a request into one function and return paginated results. The results must be first filtered by date, then other filters (paid, not paid), etc. Then search query must be executed on filtered results and final results returned. Would be great if edge cases - like no parameter passed - had a default value. I prefer Eloquent solution rather than SQL queries, but then again, if a mix of the two is working, it is fine.

Since I am fairly new to Laravel and even Databases I need some help in forming this complicated query.

My tables in mySQL look like this:

```
|  ORDERS          |
|---|--------------|------------|------------|------------|--------|
| id| provider_id  | order_paid | order_vat  | order_sum  | status |



 |       PROVIDERS     |
 |---|--------------|------------|------------|------------|--------|
 | id| name  | name | ...  | ...  | ... |




 |       PROVIDERS    
 |---|--------------|------------|------------|------------|--------|
 | id| name  | name | ...  | ...  | ... |
```

Also, in Order model:

```
public function provider()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Provider::class, 'provider_id', 'id');
}
```

in Provider model:

```
/**
 * Provider has many Orders in Eloquent Relationship.
 * @return HasMany
 */
public function orders(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
}
```

This is my Controller Function so FAR with the description what I need in the comment. It is not correct, it is just a draft for now.

In my OrdersController I use this function called filterOrders() that takes Request $request. Getting my parameters from this request.

```
public function filterOrders(Request $request)
{
    /*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| returns collection of orders filtered by:
| - DATE in format: ['2021-09-01', '2022-10-01']
| - PROVIDER ID if passed 
| - PAID, UNPAID or together as bool (both true if not passed)
| - ORDER ASC by default by creation_date
| - PAGINATE 25 records

then everything is filtered by string is passed
| - SEARCHQUERY as string in order number, provider name, order_paid (string - date)
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

$searchQuery = $request->input('searchQuery'); 
$searchForPaid = $request->input('paid'); 
$searchForUnpaid = $request->input('unpaid'); 
$dateRange = $request->input('dateRange');

$selectSql = 'orders.id = "' . $searchQuery . '"  or JSON_EXTRACT(orders.info, "$.phone") like "%' . $searchQuery . '%" or users.name like "%' . $searchQuery . '%"';

if ($provider_id != null) {
    $selectSql = $selectSql . ' and (orders.provider_id = ' . $provider_id . ')';
}

$orders = Order::whereRaw($selectSql)
    ->join('providers', 'orders.user_id', '=', 'provider.id')
    ->where('order_paid', '<>', null)
    ->whereBetween('order_paid', $dateRange)
    ->paginate(10);

return $orders;
}
```

I not only do care about the answer but also any useful tips or suggestions that will simplify the task.

Thank you in advance. Please let me know if any additional info is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
$searchQuery = $request->input('searchQuery', 'default_value'); 
$searchForPaid = $request->input('paid', 'default_value'); 
$searchForUnpaid = $request->input('unpaid', 'default_value'); 
$dateRange = $request->input('dateRange', 'default_value'); 

    $orders = Order::where('id', $searchQuery)
                ->orWhere(function($query) use ($searchQuery) {
                    $query->whereJsonContains('info->phone', $searchQuery);
                })
                ->orWhere(function($query) use ($searchQuery) {
                    $query->where('users.name', '%'.$searchQuery.'%');
                })

    if ($provider_id != null) {
        $orders->where('orders.provider_id', $provider_id);
    }

    $orders->join('users', 'orders.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->where('order_paid', '<>', null)
        ->whereBetween('order_paid', $dateRange)
        ->paginate(10);

    return $orders;
}
```

it's actually possible to supply default value's for request inputs and the queries can be optional since the `$orders` variable will just contain the so far stated sql build without executing it. This allows for optional filtering and such. I'm not sure if i used the correct syntax everywhere but hope it helps you along